# What connection does a SqlCommandBuilder use to generate queries?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database-connection

I ask because when I use  `GetUpdateCommand()` or `GetInsertCommand()` from my `SqlCommandBuilder`, the SqlCommand that is generated has its Connection member set but in a closed state. I'm wondering what connection it uses, because I don't see any connection member in this object, and the connection in `SqlCommandBuilder.DataAdapter.SelectCommand` is open (Update/Delete/InsertCommand properties are null).

Where should I check for the connection's state before running `GetUpdateCommand()` or `GetInsertCommand()`? Or should I just open their inner connection if it's closed?

BTW, I use .Net 4 with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are you sure it needs a connection? It has (needs) the meta data from SELECT

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because I get an exception ("ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed") when I execute the command generated with this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it is using the connection of `SqlCommandBuilder.DataAdapter.SelectCommand` to create the new command, however it is done only the first time You try to access the command. After the first try the command instance is retained and only its command text is regenerated.

Comment: yes, its true calling ie *GetInsertCommand* several times will result i the command-text being changed on previously returned SqlCommand-instances. But that still means that in the end the generated command will use the connection from *SqlCommandBuilder.DataAdapter.SelectCommand*

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't explain the connections' states that are different. Anyway, I bypassed the issue by re-setting the command's connection and that seem to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `GetXXXCommand` on your `SqlCommandBuilder` it will internally create a new command on the connection set on the `DataAdapter` (`DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.CreateCommand()`). This means that the connection ought to be the same for all command that the builder creates and the open/closed state should be the same as well.

What does your code look like that determines that the state is open on `SqlCommandBuilder.DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection` but not on `SqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand().Connection` !?

Comment: I'm just looking at it in the debugger after having called GetUpdateCommand(). As explained in the question's comments, I realized this when debugging an error when I run ExecuteNonQuery() on the generated command.

Comment: i wouldn't implicitly trust the debugger on this matter, rather make some real code tests... or just make sure the connection is open before executing anything against it.

Comment: Performance-wise, I believe it's better if I use an already open connection rather than open the closed one.